# sqlite3_exec crashes in prod configuration, but it works well in debug

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, crash-reports

I've to use the SQLite in iOS app. And it has got a crash in prod version, but it works well in the debug configuration.

So, I have the following crash-log:

```
Date/Time:           2016-07-07 00:09:53.53 +0300
Launch Time:         2016-07-07 00:09:31.31 +0300
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.2 (13F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Exception Note:  SIMULATED (this is NOT a crash)
Highlighted by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
ru.cookntalk.CookntalkApp failed to scene-create after 19.85s (launch took 0.15s of total time limit 20.00s)

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 25.700 (user 25.700, system 0.000), 64% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 16.300, 41% CPU

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x229e86ac pread + 20
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x231fb066 0x23190000 + 438374
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x23197b9c 0x23190000 + 31644
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x231b0724 0x23190000 + 132900
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x231afabe 0x23190000 + 129726
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x231cbb64 0x23190000 + 244580
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x231cca68 0x23190000 + 248424
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x231c0c74 0x23190000 + 199796
8   libsqlite3.dylib                0x231bfa50 sqlite3_step + 472
9   libsqlite3.dylib                0x231990ee sqlite3_exec + 402
10  Cookntalk                       0x000f88c0 +[SQLiteAccess executeSQL:withCallback:context:] (SQLiteAccess.m:119)
11  Cookntalk                       0x000f8dda +[SQLiteAccess updateWithSQL:] (SQLiteAccess.m:177)
12  Cookntalk                       0x00100f76 +[HTTPRequest getRecipesDeatil:] (HTTPRequest.m:412)
13  Cookntalk                       0x00101428 +[HTTPRequest updateDB] (HTTPRequest.m:465)
14  Cookntalk                       0x00109ac4 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:43)
15  UIKit                           0x273c0a6e -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 394
16  UIKit                           0x275ea286 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3086
17  UIKit                           0x275ee240 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1588
18  UIKit                           0x27602810 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke3286 + 36
19  UIKit                           0x275eb766 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 134
20  FrontBoardServices              0x2443bbf6 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 18
21  FrontBoardServices              0x2443baa6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 226
22  FrontBoardServices              0x2443bda4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 44
23  CoreFoundation                  0x22d2f9e6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
24  CoreFoundation                  0x22d2f5d6 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
25  CoreFoundation                  0x22d2d93e __CFRunLoopRun + 806
26  CoreFoundation                  0x22c7c1c8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
27  CoreFoundation                  0x22c7bfbc CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
28  UIKit                           0x273b9f36 -[UIApplication _run] + 526
29  UIKit                           0x273b4434 UIApplicationMain + 144
30  Cookntalk                       0x00121e74 main (main.m:14)
31  libdyld.dylib                   0x22928872 start + 2
```

And I'm using the following code:

```
+ (NSNumber *)executeSQL:(NSString *)sql withCallback:(void *)callbackFunction context:(id)contextObject {
    NSString *path = [self pathToDB];

   //NSLog(@"Database:   %@",path);

    if (!sql) return nil;

    sqlite3 *db = NULL;
    int rc = SQLITE_OK;
    NSInteger lastRowId = 0;
    int flags = SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE |  SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE;
    rc = sqlite3_open_v2([path UTF8String], &db, flags, NULL);
    if(SQLITE_OK != rc) {
        NSLog(@"Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return nil;
    } else {
        char *zErrMsg = NULL;
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], callbackFunction, (void*)contextObject, &zErrMsg);



        if(SQLITE_OK != rc) {
            NSLog(@"Can't run query '%@' error message: %s\n", sql, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        }
        lastRowId = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db);
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    NSNumber *lastInsertRowId = nil;
    if(0 != lastRowId) {
        lastInsertRowId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:lastRowId];
    }
    return lastInsertRowId;
}
```

It crashes in:

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], callbackFunction, (void*)contextObject, &zErrMsg);
```

Have someone any ideas what is it?

Comment: Perhaps you can share how `callbackFunction` was defined? Also, do you need to use `sqlite3_exec` (i.e. are you really executing multiple SQL statements)?

Comment: Completely unrelated, given that you're not using `zErrMsg`, I'd be inclined to retire it.

Comment: @Rob I call in the following way: [self executeSQL:sql withCallback:NULL context:NULL]; And Yes, there is a lot of calls sqlite3_exec. So, maybe there is a racing between calls? May be I have to make queue for calls? But  I'm using in sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);

Comment: Re racing, no, that's not it: The problem is just that you're blocking the main thread for too long. Re `NULL` for callback, that's fine. Re `zErrMsg`, sure, you're using it in `sqlite3_free`, but no where else. So why ask it for `zErrMsg` if you're not using it? Either you use `zErrMsg` (and don't call `sqlite3_errmsg` because you already have the error message), or eliminate `zErrMsg` (and the associated `sqlite3_free`) because you're not using it.

Comment: My question regarding executing multiple SQL statements in a single call to `sqlite3_exec` was just getting to the question of why you're using `sqlite3_exec` vs `sqlite3_prepare`/`sqlite3_step`/`sqlite3_finalize`. We generally prefer the latter, even though the former is easier. But let's set that aside as that's tangential to the fundamental issue that you're just tying up the main thread for too long. So dispatch this to a background queue, and this `0x8badf00d` error should go away.

Comment: Did you notice the `(this is NOT a crash)`?

Comment: The community [has discussed begging for ASAP/urgency in questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495), and has firmly resolved it is unacceptable.

Comment: @CL. Yes, exactly. But this issue "closes" app.

Answer (score 1):

The `0x8badf00d` ("ate bad food"; lol) means that your app was terminated by the watchdog process. See [Technical Note 2151](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html), which says

> The exception code `0x8badf00d` indicates that an application has been terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. The application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events. ... Whatever operation is on Thread 0 needs to be moved to a background thread, or processed differently, so that it does not block the main thread.

It would appear that you may be blocking the main thread doing so many queries. I'd suggest making sure you're doing this on a background thread or otherwise tweak this implementation.

Also, if you're doing lots of updates, consider using [transactions](http://sqlite.com/lang_transaction.html). If you're not using transactions, but are doing many updates, you may experience dramatic performance improvement if you wrap a whole series of updates within a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to me isn't that there's a problem with your sqlite code (although any process that needs to run for more than 20 seconds is ripe for optimization) but that you're running this code from the didFinishLaunching:withOptions method of the AppDelegate in some way.

If didFinishLaunching:withOptions does not finish within 20 seconds of app launch iOS will terminate your app.